# Hide the content again with js

Tags: javascript, hide, show

When i click on div.info it needs to be hidden/display:none again.
How can I do this?

html

```
<div class="floated">
<a href="#" class="showinfo">link 1</a>
<div class="info">onclick this div hide it again</div>
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.showinfo").click(function() {
        $("div.info").fadeOut();
        $(this).next("div.info").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

css

```
div.info {
    display: none;
}
div.floated {
    float: left; position:relative; height:100px; width:100px; background:#f00;
}
div.info{
    position:absolute; background:#ccc; width:100px; height:100px; top:0;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KZ3Ky/6/

Comment: Looking at your code, your fading in and out the div on click, you need to use some flag or test the current `display` status and then decide to show or hide the element

Comment: use toggle(). It is for 2 clicks. Think is that what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to set *onClick* function on the second `div`, and then you can `fadeOut` the `div` again => **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KZ3Ky/9/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("a.showinfo").click(function() {
    $("div.info").fadeOut();
    $(this).next("div.info").fadeIn();
     $("div.info").click(function(){
       $("div.info").css("display","none");
     });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to fade out div.info when you click on it?
$("div.info").css("display","none").fadeOut(); doesn't work :(

Comment: it does makes sence after seeing it lol. just found out to do a fast or slow animation: .fadeOut('fast');